# Does Bootstrap provide linkedin icons and styles?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am learning Bootstrap and I bought this theme to develop a web app.

http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0C6D0H4

I learned of this website (wrapbootstrap.com) from the book called "Bootstrap".

In the bootstrap.css coming with this theme, there are lines such as the following:

```
.icon-linkedin:before {
    content: "";
}
```

You can see linkedin icon in the top-right of the above link.

I looked at the bootstrap.css I directly downloaded from Twitter http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/ as well as the Bootstrap customization page at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html, I was unable to find any styles related to linkedin.

I am confused. How can the theme developer have linkedin related styles in its bootstrap.css file?

Thanks for any input!

Regards.

Comment: They're using an icon font, sort of like this one: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/linkedin-sign/

Comment: Looks like they are using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

Comment: Blender and Mike, thanks so much for your input. How can I generate or have the bootstrap.css file with linked-in related styles? I myself would like to know how to generate or have these linkedin related styles.

Comment: Why not have a linkedin.css file you create yourself or source elsewhere?

Comment: The reason I need to have is that the theme I bought uses Bootstrap 2.3.1 and I would like to use 2.3.2. Besides, I want to generate a RTL version. That theme does not have anything for RTL (right-to-left).

Comment: You can include FontAwesome from the BootstrapCDN `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`, or d/l the file from FontAwesome and reference them accordingly in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files you get from the Bootstrap website are just a base - there is nothing to say that anyone who downloads them can't add whichever styles they feel like in there are extra. I could add a `.stackoverflow` style or a `.facebook` (so long as I didn't trip up over any legal issues of course!)

The person behind that style has presumably just used Bootstrap as a start and added styles in as he sees fit. The extra bits are what you are paying your $49 for.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, which dispels the confusion I have. I would like to say the modification of bootstrap.css is a bad practice, making it hard to understand or maintain.

Answer (score 1):

```
<pre><i class="icon-linkedin"> </pre>
```

this is font awesome of linkedin

class="icon-linkedin"